# Can't lock private properties from being accessed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a class `ClsSubject` with a set of private properties (variables with capital "P" in their names) and letter/setter pairs. Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private PName As String
Private PStatus As String
Private PINN As String
Private POGRN As String
Private PAddress As String

Property Let Name(val As String)
    PName = val
End Property

Property Get Name() As String
    Name = PName
End Property

Property Let Status(val As String)
    PStatus = val
End Property

Property Get Status() As String
    Status = PStatus
End Property

Property Let INN(val As String)
    PINN = val
End Property

Property Get INN() As String
    INN = PINN
End Property

Property Let OGRN(val As String)
    POGRN = val
End Property

Property Get OGRN() As String
    OGRN = POGRN
End Property

Property Let Address(val As String)
     PAddress = val
End Property

Property Get Address() As String
    Address = PAddress
End Property
```

Here's an exemplar of the class (as a part of another class)

[image]

Apparently, my "private" variables are visible and available along with letters/setters. I can also get the value from them directly in the immediate window like `?Lcase.Client.PName`. As far as I know this data should be unavailable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read Mat's explanation and try [his approach](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/04/25/private-this-as-tsomething/)  instead